# Using .htaccess file to hide page extension in cPanel

Tags: .htaccess, hide, file-extension

I learnt that .htaccess file can be used to hide the page url. Example : www.mydomain.com/mypage1.html can be made to appear as www.mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com/mypage1. So I have a few questions regarding this. I have three pages say mypage1.html, mypage2.html and mypage3.html; all within the same folder in cPanel. Is there a way I can hide all three urls, like it would only appear as www.mydomain.com. Or can I have all the three pages appearing under www.mydomain.com/mycustomname/. Or will the three files appear as www.mydomain.com/mypage1/, www.mydomain.com/mypage2/ and www.mydomain.com/mypage3/ respectively.

Can anyone provide the .htaccess code for this please? Also do I need to make any changes in my html file codes? Like page1.html redirects to page2.html on click of a button; or will it be okay with the existing code.

One more question is, can I upload .htaccess file inside subfolders in cPanel? Because I have a lot of addon domains added to my cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

you can change the last line if it contains .php

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```